# What happens when Maoki uses Twisted Advance on a teleporting Twisted Fate and Nocturne?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know Maoki follows flashes and dashes with his Twisted Advance, and does not follow blue pill and tele summoner, but what about TF and Nocturne ults? Does it cancel, take Mao part of the way to the target's new location then stop (like some target spells and autos)? Or is whether or not Mao follows determined by how far away they teleport?

Answer (score 1):

It is in most cases impossible, Maokai can follow even an ulting TF but the destination must be on the same screen. Check this clip out :